# What to do with Memgraph Lab error: Your connection is invalid, please reconnect again.?

Tags: memgraphdb

I started the Memgraph using `docker run -it -p 7687:7687 -p 7444:7444 -p 3000:3000 -v mg_lib:/var/lib/memgraph memgraph/memgraph-platform`. I opened a Memgraph Lab using `localhost:3000`. Then I shutdown the Memgraph, and started it again. In the log I can see the flowing error.

What is this? I didn't change any network settings or ports.

```
[2023-09-27 05:45:49.785] ERROR: [lab] Your connection is invalid, please reconnect again.
    err: {
      "type": "LabForbiddenError",
      "message": "Your connection is invalid, please reconnect again.",
      "stack":
          LabForbiddenError: Your connection is invalid, please reconnect again.
              at SessionService.getMemgraphServiceBySession (/lab/dist-backend/services/session.js:22:19)
              at /lab/dist-backend/routes/api/stats.js:30:40
              at asyncUtilWrap (/lab/node_modules/express-async-handler/index.js:3:20)
              at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/lab/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
              at next (/lab/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
              at /lab/dist-backend/middlewares/validator.js:21:13
              at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/lab/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
              at next (/lab/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:144:13)
              at Route.dispatch (/lab/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:114:3)
              at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/lab/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
      "status": 403,
      "name": "LabForbiddenError"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably, you are seeing this error because you have a browser window with Memgraph's UI open and it needs to refresh its connection. Just reconnect all connections.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Refresh did the trick. Thank you @Ivelin for your help!